# Calling a static C# method from a managed C++/CLI thread

Tags: c#, c++-cli

I seem to be having issue with calling static C# methods.

I currently have 2 DLLs that I inject into an ancient legacy app and then execute a static method as seen in the code below:

Module.cs

```
using System;

namespace Debugger
{
    public static class Module
    {
        public static void Initialize()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("YES");
        }
    }
}
```

dllmain.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include <windows.h>

#pragma once

#pragma managed

using namespace System;
using namespace System::Reflection;
using namespace Debugger;

DWORD WINAPI MainThread(LPVOID param)
{
    AllocConsole();

    Console::WriteLine("Test");

    Debugger::Module::Initialize();

    FreeLibraryAndExitThread((HMODULE)param, 0);

    return 0;
}

#pragma unmanaged

HMODULE hModule;
BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, DWORD reason, LPVOID reserved) 
{
    switch (reason) 
    {
        case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
            CreateThread(0, 0, MainThread, hModule, 0, 0);
            break;
        case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
            FreeLibrary(hModule);
            break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

As a result: I get the console open, the 'Test' message pops up but 'YES' doesn't - instead, the app crashes.

Comment: Does it also crash if you remove the FreeLibraryAndExitThread call? I ask, because if this is your complete code, hModule is not initialized.

Comment: What is the error message of the crash? Check event viewer.

Comment: @KlausGütter It doesn't crash if I comment out `Debugger::Module::Initialize();`, but I'll check about the FreeLibraryAndExitThread thing.

@kennyzx I think you are onto something, while I didn't find anything about this app - I found something about my test app that I run tests on right before I test it on the legacy app - it says:
'Application: TestApp.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.IO.FileNotFoundException
   at <Module>.MainThread(Void*)'

Comment: Injecting managed code is very, very risky.  Crashing the injected process is pretty easy to do, a simple exception gets the job done.  Like FileNotFoundException when the jitter can't find the assembly that contains the Module type.

Comment: @HansPassant Yes, I'm well aware of that, but the debugger will be ran sporadically - when no other tool helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving the DLL to the same folder as executable I'm injecting into fixed the issue.

Comment: So unlike C# project, a C++/CLI project doesn’t copy its dependencies to the Output folder. Am I correct?